# Using 'Mlxtend' with 'TensorFlow' or 'Pytorch'

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, regression, pytorch

Is it possible to create a simple stacking implementation for regression with '**Mlxtend**' using models created by '**TensorFlow**' or '**Pytorch**' however the documentation only supports examples that contain '**scikit-learn**'?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mlextend allows stacking of multiple neural network models however this log describe a process by which you can stack such models . hope this helps

- https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/